# How to pass Discriminated Union as a parameter in a function? F#

Tags: f#

How to pass a parameter in a function if the defined type is a Discriminated Union? For example I want to pass in an object of type Color where the colorB is set to "blue". Inside the function I want to check if colorB is set to is blue.

```
type Color = ColorA of string | ColorB of string

let IsColorBlue (a:Color): bool = 
    match a with
    | a -> if a.ColorB = "blue" then true // <- How to check if ColorB is blue ?

IsColorBlue (Color-Object)   // <- How do I call this?
```

Comment: First you need to match that you have a `ColorB` and not a `ColorA`, which you haven't done in your code

Comment: Also please provide a proper [mcve], you haven't defined `Color-Object` anywhere

Answer (score 2):

To use pattern matching to check whether a `Color` is `colorB` with a specific value, you can use the following syntax:

```ml
let IsColorBlue (a:Color): bool = 
    match a with
    | ColorB "blue" -> true
    | _ -> false
```

To create values of type `Color`, you can write `ColorA "some"` or `ColorB "some"`. For example:

```ml
IsColorBlue (ColorB "blue") // true
IsColorBlue (ColorB "red")  // false - not blue
IsColorBlue (ColorA "blue")  // false - not ColorB
```

Comment: What if you need to check 2 parameters? Like if ColorA = blue & ColorB = blue at the same time. How do you call the function & how to write if else with pattern matching?